# Get the AVG of an AVG result

Tags: sql

I have this query :

```
SELECT AVG(legs.avg) FROM legs INNER JOIN matchs ON matchs.id = legs.match_id WHERE matchs.player_id=4 GROUP BY match_id
```

Which allows me to get the average of the attribute "legs.avg".

The problem is that I get several results for this query, one for each matchs.id.

I need to get the average of these different results, so only one row with the total average.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Just remove the group by?

Comment: The group BY is the problem. Are you sure you need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to get the "average of averages":

```
SELECT avg(l_avg)
FROM (SELECT AVG(l.avg) as l_avg
      FROM legs l INNER JOIN
           matchs m
           ON m.id = l.match_id
      WHERE m.player_id = 4
      GROUP BY l.match_id 
     ) lm;
```

There are two other approaches with no subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(l.avg) as l_avg
FROM legs l INNER JOIN
     matchs m
     ON m.id = l.match_id
WHERE m.player_id = 4;
```

Or:

```
SELECT SUM(l.avg) / COUNT(DISTINCT l.match_id) as l_avg
FROM legs l INNER JOIN
     matchs m
     ON m.id = l.match_id
WHERE m.player_id = 4;
```

These do *not* return the same value.  The first is the overall average and the second is weighted so each match has a weight of exactly 1.  This is the same as the first first query, with the subquery.

Without sample data, it is not clear which version you really want.

Comment: thanks, the second one worked perfectly for me :). Thank you all anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :-

```
select avg(leg_avg) from (SELECT AVG(legs.avg) leg_avg FROM legs INNER JOIN matchs ON matchs.id = legs.match_id WHERE matchs.player_id=4 GROUP BY match_id) a11
```